# Where is the editor layout stored in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open a folder that I've already worked in, VSCode is clever and reopens it in the exact same layout I already had it. However, I have absolutely no clue how it does that - I can't find a config file or anything anywhere, which is something I'd love to have; in my specific usecase I create a lot of workspaces and they all have the same sort of structure, so if I could save that layout so I didn't have to recreate it every time it'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ends up being super annoying... they're stored in `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage` in some hashed looking folder names, which contain a pretty useless `workspace.json` file (all workspaces) and all other info stored in a `*.vscdb` (and its associated `*.backup` file), which is a SQLite Format 3 file storing all that information. It's barely used as a database from what I can see, a `json` file could do just as well, but I digress...

tl;dr they're a pain to get out.

Comment: Also, extensions don't have access to either the actual active layout or the settings contained in the `.vscdb` file. This makes writing an extension to reset your layout (or using several layout profiles) impossible.

Comment: PS: This might interest you: [Explore user profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116740)

Comment: oh, amazing that there's going to be something like it soon!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a lot of the UI settings by clicking the Manage(⚙) on the bottom of the Side bar > Profiles > Show Profile Contents then expanding the `UI State` section. There is a link for the `globalState.json` file and I was able to find several of the personalisations under various "workbench.X.Y" keys.

There seems to be one such `globalState.json` file for each profile I've defined in VS Code.

Answer (score -3):

VSCode mainly saves all of the preferences and user choices in the *`settings.json`* file. Moreover, you can actually set your preferences in VSCode Settings. But if you want to copy/paste your workspace settings to different workspaces, I guess the best choice would be to look at your settings.json layout settings.

- Go to File > Preferences and adding them in the right pane, in "User Settings" if you want to keep them for all workspaces or in "Workspace Settings" for this workspace only.
- To see settings for layouts and explorer, search for `explorer`.

You can read more about `settings.json` defaults and attributes exposed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-and-security)

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean. For example, I have two files in split screen, with both of them resized very specifically. This state is saved between sessions, but I don't know where. This is completely different to `settings.json`.